# rails validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, message

My Rails app began returning funky validation error messages of this form upon create/save of a model.

{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved
There were problems with the following fields:
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably upgraded Ruby to a version that does not work well with your version of Rails. I think that if you use Ruby 1.9 you have to at least use Rails 2.3.9 if I'm not mistaken.

Here is a changelog for Rails 2.3.9: [ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released)